# parse.com: SerializationException deserializing JSON objects with "__type" property

Tags: c#, json, parse-platform, uwp, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm developing a Windows 10 UWP app and can't seem to get rid of this error:
"An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

I'm using the Rest API to retrieve values from a Data Store on Parse and instantiate objects.
Here's what my Class looks like

```
public class ImageTest
{
    public class Image
    {
        public string __type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string createdAt { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string objectId { get; set; }
        public string updatedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's what my JSON output looks like:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-11-16T02:04:17.403Z",
        "image": {
            "__type": "File",
            "name": "stark.jpg",
            "url": "http://xyz.parse.com/stark.jpg"
        },
        "name": "Stark",
        "objectId": "2ypGrvkvg0",
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-16T02:04:23.121Z"
    },
    {
        "createdAt": "2015-11-16T02:04:31.409Z",
        "image": {
            "__type": "File",
            "name": "targaryen.jpg",
            "url": "http://xyz.parse.com/targaryen.jpg"
        },
        "name": "Targaryen",
        "objectId": "otgO3scX3k",
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-16T02:04:40.094Z"
    }
]
}
```

The details of the error message are as follows:
Additional information: Element ':image' contains data of the ':File' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'File' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deserialize your JSON, and `"__type"` is a *reserved property* for this serializer.  It is used to identify derived types of polymorphic types.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Preserving Type Information**
>
> To preserve type identity, when serializing complex types to JSON a "type hint" can be added, and the deserializer recognizes the hint and acts appropriately. The "type hint" is a JSON key/value pair with the key name of "__type" (two underscores followed by the word "type"). The value is a JSON string of the form "DataContractName:DataContractNamespace" (anything up to the first colon is the name)...
>
> The type hint is very similar to the xsi:type attribute defined by the XML Schema Instance standard and used when serializing/deserializing XML.
>
> **Data members called "__type" are forbidden due to potential conflict with the type hint.**

Thus you cannot *manually* add this property to your class and have it translate correctly.

You can, however, leverage the serializer's handling of polymorphism to read and write the `"__type"` *automatically*, by defining a class hierarchy of image information in which your `Image` type is a subclass of the expected type.  Let's rename it to `FileImage` for clarity:

```
public class ImageTest
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    [KnownType(typeof(FileImage))]
    public abstract class ImageBase
    {
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "File", Namespace = "")]
    public sealed class FileImage : ImageBase
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "url")]
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Result
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string createdAt { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public FileImage image { get { return imageBase as FileImage; } set { imageBase = value; } }

        [DataMember(Name = "image")] // Need not be public if DataMember is applied.
        ImageBase imageBase { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string objectId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string updatedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now everything should work.

If later you find that server is sending JSON data with additional `"__type"` values and property data (e.g. an embedded Base64 image) you can now easily modify your data model to add additional subclasses to `ImageBase`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to have resolved the error and the program compiles now. How do I access members of class Result and class FileImage when binding those as DataContext (specifically name and url)?

Comment: @JasonBourne - the `image` property is still there and publicly accessible.  It casts the underlying `ImageBase` property to a `FileImage` and returns it.  So you should be able to bind to that.