# DataContractJsonSerializer Deserialization problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datacontractjsonserializer

I need to De-serialize Json array which is given bellow ....

```
[
    {
        "GeoType": 1,
        "ID": "2650f7d2-7a5e-4b63-856c-07600fa2a854",
        "Name": "Afghanistan",
        "CapitalCity": null,
        "CountryBoundaries": null,
        "CountryCode": "AF",
        "ISO": "AFG",
        "Parent": {
            "__type": "Region:#MEDEX.Library.Geo",
            "GeoType": 0,
            "ID": "6dc22edb-d711-4253-937f-242b0cd3c011",
            "Name": "Asia",
            "Code": "Asi"
        },
        "RegionID": "6dc22edb-d711-4253-937f-242b0cd3c011"
    },
    {
        "GeoType": 1,
        "ID": "3917c1c8-ee01-4e9b-8622-0fac9e9194ab",
        "Name": "Albania",
        "CapitalCity": null,
        "CountryBoundaries": null,
        "CountryCode": "AL",
        "ISO": "ALB",
        "Parent": {
            "__type": "Region:#MEDEX.Library.Geo",
            "GeoType": 0,
            "ID": "b7ebd500-45e6-4a48-a2ef-f38fe99e7352",
            "Name": "Europe",
            "Code": "Eur"
        },
        "RegionID": "b7ebd500-45e6-4a48-a2ef-f38fe99e7352"
    }
]
```

My object definition is:

```
[DataContract]
public class Parent1
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, Type> __type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string GeoType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Country
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string GeoType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Parent1 Parent { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RegionID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ISO { get; set; }
}
```

it is always getting error:

> {"Element ':Parent' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEDEX.Library.Geo:Region'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add the type corresponding to 'Region' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to the serializer."}

Could you please suggest me any solution. I even don understand what this error means. Please suggest.

Comment: It would be useful to also add the part of your code that does the actual deserialization

Comment: Related or similar: [parse.com: SerializationException deserializing JSON objects with “__type” property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33746518/3744182).  Does the answer to that question give you sufficient information to solve your problem also?

Answer (score 0):

Add [KnownType(Region)] to class Parent1 attributes

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33747002/3744182) to *[parse.com: SerializationException deserializing JSON objects with "__type" property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33746518/3744182)*, your problem is that the `"__type"` is a *reserved property* for `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  It is used to identify derived types of polymorphic types.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/stand-alone-json-serialization#preserving-type-information):

> **Preserving Type Information**
>
> To preserve type identity, when serializing complex types to JSON a "type hint" can be added, and the deserializer recognizes the hint and acts appropriately. The "type hint" is a JSON key/value pair with the key name of "__type" (two underscores followed by the word "type"). The value is a JSON string of the form "DataContractName:DataContractNamespace" (anything up to the first colon is the name)...
>
> The type hint is very similar to the xsi:type attribute defined by the XML Schema Instance standard and used when serializing/deserializing XML.
>
> **Data members called "__type" are forbidden due to potential conflict with the type hint.**

Thus you cannot *manually* add this property to your class and have it translate correctly.

You can, however, leverage the serializer's handling of polymorphism to read and write the `"__type"` *automatically*, by defining a class hierarchy of regions in which a `Region` class inherits from some base type, say `RegionBase`, which is referred to by `Country.Parent`:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEDEX.Library.Geo")]
public class Country
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string GeoType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public RegionBase Parent { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RegionID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ISO { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEDEX.Library.Geo")]
[KnownType(typeof(Region))]
public class RegionBase
{
}

[DataContract(
    Name = "Region", 
    Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEDEX.Library.Geo")]
public class Region : RegionBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string GeoType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize as a `List<Country>`, since your outer JSON container is an array.

Notes:

- The type hint is in the format `"DataContractName:DataContractNamespace"`.

  In addition, as explained in [*Reducing the Size of Type Hints*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/stand-alone-json-serialization#reducing-the-size-of-type-hints), the prefix `#` in the type hint is a shortcut for `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/`.  Thus `Region` must have the following data contract name:

  ```
  [DataContract(
      Name = "Region", 
      Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MEDEX.Library.Geo")]
  ```
- The type hierarchy in my answer is sufficient to deserialize the sample JSON, but it may not be ideal.  For instance, in practice there may be other subtypes of `RegionBase` that share properties with `Region` (such as `ID`), and so those properties should get moved to the base class.  Or there may be other possible subclasses of `RegionBase` not shown in your question, e.g. `"SomeOtherKindOfRegion:#MEDEX.Library.Geo"`, which will need to be added to the model.
- Since it appears this JSON comes from a WCF service, hopefully it has published its [Service Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-publish-metadata-for-a-service-using-a-configuration-file).  If so, it will allow you to generate a client *automatically* using *Add Service Reference* in Visual Studio.  For instructions on how to do this, see [*How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client) and [*How to: Add, Update, or Remove a Service Reference*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).  Automatic client generation should avoid the difficulty you are having.

  For examples of this see *[How to deserialize JSON with unnamed collection of types using DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34384838/3744182)* or *[How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service (not make a call)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/950150/3744182)*.
- The data contract serializer must be informed of all possible polymorphic subtypes of `RegionBase` via the [Known Type mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types).

Comment: @SadaySarkar - Glad to help.  If your question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147531).